# What is the difference between stable and master?

Tags: github

I'm not seeing this question answered online anywhere.  Can anyone assist?

What is the difference between stable and master?

Comment: I needed to know the answer to this question too, and could not find it anywhere online. Fortunately, since it was asked here, I got my answer. Great question! Thanks for asking it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to git branches (I'm assuming this) then typically with web applications master would be the current live branch.  The assumption is that everything that merges into master will go live. A stable branch should refer to a well-tested working version of your application and should be named with a version number. This branch should also be tagged so you can branch and/or fork from different versions of your code. It doesn't have to be called "stable"...you can call branches whatever you please...but in this case maybe your last stable branch would be `stable-v1.2` for example.

Comment: If you're looking for more information, I found [this post](https://gist.github.com/digitaljhelms/4287848) helpful. It includes a pretty diagram at the bottom which solidified the workflow for me.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no difference between the two besides that master is usually the default branch with the most up to date code. You may have seen a stable branch on another repository that is just what they chose to name it.